# Get the query work with % (ajax+javascript+html)

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, sqlite

I am trying to get all the results where its album title contains "Led".

using terminal,

```
select * from collection where album like '%Led%';
```

this actullay get the item I need, however, using javascript,

```
access("select album from collection where album like '%" + document.getElementById("title").value + "%'", findCallback);
```

Please assum that above, document.getElementById("title").value is "Led
"

Anyway, above query on javascript doesn't work.

I guess there is problem on using %. How can I use % on javascript for a query statement?

(also I should not use "match" but only "like" because it doesn't support..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what wrapper you are using but you can bind wildcards `%%` in binding parameter

```
access("select album from collection where album like ?",['%'+ document.getElementById("title").value.toString() +'%'], findCallback);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9d8tpve5/